# Facebook JS API- cannot get image to post?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, stream, publish

I'm trying to post to a wall using FB.ui method, and I have it working but as soon as I try to implement a picture into the post it's failing hard.

I have figured it out using FB.api() method but would like the user to have the popup and select "Post" as opposed to it posting immediately.

My code is as follows:

```
FB.ui({ method : 'feed', 
                    message: userPrompt,
                    link   :  hrefLink,
                    caption:  hrefTitle,
                    attachment: {       
                        name: 'Test',
                        caption: 'Test2',
                        description: ( 'Test4'),
                        'media': [{ 'type': 'image',
                                    'src': 'srcLink',
                                    'href': 'imageLink'
                                }]
                    }
                  });
```

If anyone can help me out that'd be great- this is really starting to irritate me!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check if FireBug reports a specific error? Also, I know that this is not official documentation, but it has helped me in the past: http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.ui

Answer (score 0):

If this is your exact code then your variables for srcLink and imageLink should not be contained in quotes.

Comment: It is not the exact code, I changed the URLs with those names just because it's a private project right now. Any other ideas?

Comment: Ahh got it figured out! Thanks!

Comment: If you figured it out, help other folks out and post an answer.